# compering string from bin file to fgets() string

Tags: c, string, file, strcmp, bin

In my code I'm creating 3 new files.

If the file "users" do not exist I create one with some information to initialize the file.

After that, I want to compare a string from the user using fgets() function
and then compare the string to the ones in the file (the password and the ID)
you can see the struct: user, in the beginning of the code.
Now when I use "strcmp" it's giving me always '1'.

```
enter code here

#define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "doubly_list.h"

typedef struct user {
    int SecurityLevel;
    char ID[15];
    char Password[15];
    char FullName[20];
}user;

typedef struct items {
    char movie_name[20];
    char producer_name[20];
    int release_date_year, release_date_month, release_date_day;
    float rating;
    int serial_number;
    bool is_adult_video;
}items;

void main()
{
    char id_input[15], password_input[15];
    int day, month, year, hours, mins, SecurityLevel;


FILE* log;
log = fopen("log.txt", "a");
fclose(log);

FILE* users;
users = fopen("users.dat", "rb+");

user new_user;
if (users == NULL)
{
    FILE* users;
    users = fopen("users.dat", "ab+");
    new_user.SecurityLevel = 3;
    strcpy(&new_user.Password, "admin");
    strcpy(&new_user.ID, "admin");
    strcpy(&new_user.FullName, "System_Manager");
    fwrite(&new_user, sizeof(new_user), 1, users);
    fclose(users);
}


FILE* item;
item = fopen("users.dat", "ab+");
fclose(item);

        printf("Enter ID: ");
        fgets(id_input, 15, stdin);
        flushall();
        printf("Enter Password : ");
        fgets(password_input, 15, stdin);

        log = fopen("log.txt", "a+");
        fprintf(log, "\nthe user entered the ID : %s", id_input);
        fprintf(log, "the user entered the password : %s", password_input);

        FILE* users_out= fopen("users.dat", "rb");
        fread(&new_user, sizeof(user), 1, users_out);

        int result= result = strcmp(password_input, new_user.Password);
        printf("\n%d\n", result);

        if (strcmp(password_input, new_user.Password)==0)
            printf("\nLog in was successful.....\n\n");
        else
            printf("\nLog In was Unseccessful.....\n\n");

        fclose(log);
        fclose(users_out);

system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code used `fgets()` and failed to remove trailing `'\n'`.  Also input buffer was then at least 1 too small

```
printf("Enter ID: ");
fgets(id_input, 15, stdin); // likely has \n in `id_input`.
```

Instead consider a helper function such as

```
// read a line of input
// 1: Success
// 0: bad input
// EOF: end-of-file or rare input error
int read_line80(const char *prompt, char *dest, size_t sz) {
  char buf[80 * 2]; // Be generous to allow for casual over long input
  // If VLAs allowed, consider `char buf[sz + 2];`

  if (prompt) fputs(prompt, stdout);
  fflush(stdout);  // Make certain output seen before input

  if (sz > 0) dest[0] = '\0';
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return EOF;

  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len > 0 && buf[len-1] == '\n') {
    buf[--len] = '\0';
  }

  // Maybe add extra code here to see if `fgets()` did not read everything

  if (len >= sz) return 0;
  strcpy(dest, buf);
  return 1;
}
```

Then

```
    if (read_line("Enter ID: ", id_input, sizeof id_input == 1) &&
        read_line("Enter Password : ", password_input, sizeof password_input == 1)) {
      // Oh happy day!
      // Use input
    } else {
      // Fail
    }
```

The key point is that user input is evil and best to read a *line* of input in a helper function and have it deal with I/O nuances.  Let the calling code focus on the non-I/O aspects of input.